# How to fetch Contact number using linkedin mobile sdk

Tags: android, linkedin-api

```
private static final String host = "api.linkedin.com"; 
private static final String PROTECTED_URL_GET_CURRENT_USER_PROFILE = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,industry)";
```

How do I to add a field to get contact number?

Is there any other method to get details from Linked-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***User the following urls to fetch LinkedIn data.***

```
private static final String HOST = "api.linkedin.com";
private static final String FETCH_BASIC_INFO = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry)";
private static final String FETCH_CONTACT = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(num-connections,email-address,phone-numbers,main-address)";
private static final String FETCH_PROFILE_PIC = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(picture-urls::(original))";
private static final String SHARE_URL = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~/shares";
```

***Don't forget to set permission for accessing above info at both mobile app as well as while registering app in LinkedIn***

```
  private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.R_CONTACTINFO);
}
```

Comment: seems like its not working do i need to use partners program of linkedin to acess contact numbers of a signed in user?